# How to permanently disable the annoying "RCS chats" popup in Messages app

Tags: sms, google-messages, rich-communication-services

I have a Pixel 3. I try to avoid using SMS and instead use Signal whenever possible. When I do use SMS (the Messages app), I don't want "RCS chats" to be enabled. But nearly every time I open the Messages app, I'm prompted with a popup where the "Agree" button is very prominent.

[image: Messages screenshot]

I do not want to agree to use RCS chats. I want my choice (when I click "Use Messages without RCS chats") to be permanent.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a *two year old* [Google community question about this](https://support.google.com/messages/thread/100303947?hl=en), which Google as usual chose not to respond to, and just locked up the question.

On my Pixel 6a, I had enabled RCS previously. After seeing this question, I disabled RCS and opened messages app many times over two days. I did not get the enable RCS popup again

Enabling RCS by tapping agree and then from settings disabling RCS is a hack that worked for me. I am not sure if this behavior is OS version dependent or the logic behind this ( I guess it's some kind of promo popup to encourage RCS usage).

This may or not work for OP but making it into an answer that may help somebody.

Comment: Thank you. I will accept this answer preemptively and will try it out next time that popup happens. I know I could go switch the setting right now, but I'm curious to come back and check the date of this comment when it happens and see how long the interval was.

Comment: You are welcome. Also if it doesn't work please feel free to comment and unaccept as well!